# Stop automatically setting apps as default

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, default-applications, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have an AT&T Samsung Note4 currently running Marshmallow 6.0.1.

In the past it and all other Android phones used to prompt me for and app
to open files or links with. The menu wold have a sellection of apps and 'Once' and 'Always' buttons. An app would only become default for a given link/file type by pressing 'Always'. Otherwise I would get prompted each time.

Not too long ago this behavior changed. The 'Once' and 'Always' buttons are gone and apps automatically become default after the first choice. This is fine for some files/links but not others.

There are many different kinds of things I want to do with some file types (eg pdfs) and I use different apps for each. Now I either have to unset the default each time or open the file in whatever the current default is and than 'share' it to the app I actually want. This is a pain and not all apps are equally good at sharing to other apps.

**How can I get the old behaviour back?** Or at least select some file/link types to not have a default associated with them? I know how to unset default apps in settings; I am after a way to avoid needing to do that for files/links I open with multiple apps.

I am not sure if this change is due to some update or if it is something I enabled unintentionally
FWIW, I also have a Huawei running Android 4.4.4 that still has the old behavior

---

This [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165798/keep-asking-for-apps-on-every-action-on-marshmallow) is about the same problem in a specific context, but i am after a solution to the general problem that none of the commants & answers there address.

Comment: Did you try this method ? http://android.stackexchange.com/a/155408/131553

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem but it looks like it's corrected in later updates of marshmallow according to https://www.greenbot.com/article/2991086/how-to-change-your-default-browser-and-phone-apps-in-android-marshmallow.html
So I'm going to try updating and hope it works for both of us.

Answer (score -1):

On my S8
Settings>Apps>default apps>default app selection